# Listview Item Background Color not updating when adding new item Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-listview

I'm having issue regarding expansion tile collapsedBackgroundColor which is item of the ListView.builder. You can checkout below code for that.

```
ListView.builder(
 itemCount: mqttEvents.length,
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   return ExpansionTile(
     collapsedBackgroundColor: alarmPriorityCategory
                                        [alarmPriorityCategory
                                            .indexWhere((element) =>
                                                mqttEvents[index].priority <=
                                                element.priority)]
                                        .color
                                        .replaceAll("#", "0x"),
         ..............
   );
 }
),
```

Where as **alarmPriorityCategory** is the list of colors. which is as below

```
[
  {
    "Color":"0xff28B542",
    "Priority":10
  },
  {
    "Color":"0xffffff00",
    "Priority":30
  },
  .....
]
```

Now the issue is. The above code is working perfectly when list is same. But when we update the list or add the new item in that list at 0 position. Then it's still shows the same color as earlier one even though if I print that color in text it's different. Don't know what's the issue is. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: specify a key property for the items

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: please refer to this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc